# Unable to display component on screen

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<template>
  <div v-for="corpus in getCorpora" v-bind:key="corpus.id">
    <Corpus v-bind="corpus" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import Corpus from "../components/Corpus";
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";
export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["getCorpora"]),
  },
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch("fetchCorpora");
  },
  components: {
    Corpus,
  },
};
</script>
```

what is the problem with this code? I am trying to get component data to be displayed dynamically whenever I enter new data in it.

Comment: what is the code of <Courpus> component?

Comment: https://github.com/flurin-g/actionannotator-frontend/blob/bc971201acf4f2276e53eea9c59e65679184a18a/src/components/Corpus.vue

Comment: How are you entering the new data? what error are you recieving?

Comment: What do you see in your Vue devtools? The `corpus` state is maybe empty?

Comment: When i click on corpora tab page remains empty it didn't display button to add corpora name.

Comment: It display components when i write  <div >
    <Corpus v-bind="corpus" />
  </div>                     instead of <div v-for="corpus in getCorpora" v-bind:key="corpus.id">
    <Corpus v-bind="corpus" />
  </div>

Comment: @MuhammadOwais I added an answer, Hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine if `getCorpora` has been updated/reactive. I just created a demo, Can you please have a look and try to find the root cause of the issue you are facing.

Demo (I just added an input and on blur, input value has been added into a getCorpora array) **:**

```js
Vue.component('corpus', {
  props: ['childmsg'],
  template: '<p>{{ childmsg }}</p>'
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    corpus: '',
    getCorpora: [{
        id: 1,
      name: 'Corpus A' 
    }, {
        id: 2,
      name: 'Corpus B' 
    }, {
        id: 3,
      name: 'Corpus C' 
    }]
  },
  methods: {
    addCorpus() {
      if (this.corpus) {
        const index = this.getCorpora.at(-1).id + 1
            this.getCorpora.push({
            id: index,
          name: this.corpus
        })
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  Add corpus : <input type="text" v-model="corpus" @blur="addCorpus">
  <div v-for="corpus in getCorpora" v-bind:key="corpus.id">
    <Corpus :childmsg="corpus.name"></Corpus>
  </div>
</div>
```